# OpenCV fillPoly vs floodFill discrepancy

Tags: c++, c, opencv, flood-fill

I'm confused as to why these two variations of essentially the same thing are giving me different results: fillPoly gives correct results whereas floodFill does not.

I have a 7-vertex closed convex polygon that is essentially a rectangle placed diagonally on a 40000x80000 (rows x cols) background. My method of drawing the filled polygon with floodFill is to loop through the vertices and draw each edge line with (pseudocode)

```
for (int i = 0; i < nvert - 1; i++)
    line(canvas, xvert[i], yvert[i], xvert[i+1], yvert[i+1])
```

with the edge value being 255 and the line thickness being 1. I can confirm that it draws the boundary exactly as I expect. I then get the centroid of the vertices and do a floodFill with `floodFill(canvas, ic, jc)`. The result is a bottom-half filled polygon, but not starting at the row `jc`. If I try and do a second floodFill starting at another point further up internal to the polygon, it only fills the row of the point I try.

When I run fillPoly (again, pseudocode) with `fillPoly(canvas, xvert, yvert, nvert)`, it fills the polygon on the large canvas perfectly.

Shouldn't these two functions be doing the same thing? Obviously there is something I'm missing with floodFill, but I can't find it in the documentation or any examples online. I am using a C interface to the C++ OpenCV, so I send in things like integer arrays to interface functions that convert everything from the C structures to the necessary C++ structures for OpenCV to use. I have no other problems doing any of the basic drawing with OpenCV.

Could the large size I'm dealing with give floodFill problems? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Per request, although not exactly. As a mockup this is what the floodFill looks like, except just imagine the boundary a single pixel thin and on the scale of 40k x 80k pixels:

[image]

Again, as a mockup this is what fillPoly looks like (same scale considerations):

[image]

Comment: You should post a picture of what's going on.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I just made a little mockup. Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there a limitation of the stack depth somewhere ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I believe that may be the case. I have just tested on some smaller sizes like 40k x 20k and the line drawing + flood fill method works just fine

Comment: 80k is above what an unsigned 16 bits integer can store. In the source code, you can observe that some coordinates are stored as `ushort`. If you look at the abscissa of the endpoint of the upper filled run, it seems close to 65535.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, block processing it is then. Thanks